# How can I prevent the textarea from stretching beyond his parent DIV element? (google-chrome issue only)

Tags: css, google-chrome, textarea

How can I prevent the textarea from stretching beyond its parent DIV element?

I have this textarea inside a table which is inside a DIV and it seems that it causes the entire table to stretch out of its bounds.

You can see an example of the same situation even in a more simple case, just putting a text area inside a div (like what is used here in www.stackoverflow.com)

You can see from the images below that the textarea can stretch beyond the size of its parent? How do I prevent this?

I'm kind of new to CSS so I don't really know what CSS attributes should I be using. I tried several like *display*, and *overflow*.
But they don't seem to do the trick.
Anything else I might have missed?

[image: the div section]

[image: the text area]

UPDATE:
HTML

CSS

```
textarea {
    max-width: 50%;
}
#container {
    width: 80%;
    border: 1px solid red;
}    
#cont2{
    width: 60%;
    border: 1px solid blue;
} ​
```

If you put this code inside the http://jsfiddle.net,
you will see that they act differently. Although the textarea is limited to the percentage declared in its css style, it is still possible to get it to cause its parent table to be as large as it wants to be, and then you can see that it spills over its parent border.
Any thoughts on how to fix this? 
​

Answer (score 202, accepted):

To disable resizing completely:

```
textarea {
    resize: none;
}
```

To allow only vertical resizing:

```
textarea {
    resize: vertical;
}
```

To allow only horizontal resizing:

```
textarea {
    resize: horizontal;
}
```

Or you can limit size:

```
textarea {
    max-width: 100px; 
    max-height: 100px;
}
```

To limit size to parents width and/or height:

```
textarea {
    max-width: 100%; 
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: can i still keep the manual stretching available just limit the stretching stays in the bound of it's parent element?

Comment: Is that a CSS attribute? it's not valid in css 2.1

Comment: Yes, it's CSS attribute but it will not validate. I also updated my answer.

Comment: i wonder i f i could make it work also with the width as a precentage and not a fixed number of pixels. because i want to allow the user to resize the text area but not break down the screen structure.

Comment: Setting max-width as percentage works well - http://jsfiddle.net/paGE3/ . By the way, please accept my answer if it's working.

Comment: @Itay Levin - try to define cell's and tables width. And this is another question now...

Comment: I actually used max-width: 100%; so it stays at whatever initial width it was to begin with.

Comment: Using percentage on the parent this doesn't really work: https://jsfiddle.net/2bvu7qyx/1/ Is there an update version of this answer?

Comment: @Dollique i see no problem in your example. Your textarea cannot be resized larger than it's parent. If your issue is that textarea can be stretched a few pixels larger than parent then it's because of box-sizing. I fixed it there: https://jsfiddle.net/wzargy9q/

Comment: @MārisKiseļovs The problem is more, that it doesn't work reliably. Try to stretch a few times and after 2-3 tries (without reloading) it will still go over the max-width.

Comment: @Dollique I cannot reproduce that. You should ask separate question with this fiddle and add screenshots with your bug. It's not related to rogiinal question anymore.

Answer (score 21):

**Textarea resize control** is available via the [CSS3 resize property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/resize):

```css
textarea { resize: both; } /* none|horizontal|vertical|both */
textarea.resize-vertical{ resize: vertical; }
textarea.resize-none { resize: none; }
```

Allowable values self-explanatory: `none` (disables textarea resizing), `both`, `vertical` and `horizontal`.

**Notice** that in Chrome, Firefox and Safari the default is `both`.

If you want to constrain the width and height of the textarea element, that's not a problem:  these browsers also respect `max-height`, `max-width`, `min-height`, and `min-width` CSS properties to provide resizing within certain proportions.

**Code example**:

```css
#textarea-wrapper {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  width: 300px;
}

#textarea-wrapper textarea {
  min-height:50px;
  max-height:120px;
  width: 290px;
}

#textarea-wrapper textarea.vertical { 
  resize: vertical;
}
```

```html
<div id="textarea-wrapper">
  <label for="resize-default">Textarea (default):</label>
  <textarea name="resize-default" id="resize-default"></textarea>
  
  <label for="resize-vertical">Textarea (vertical):</label>
  <textarea name="resize-vertical" id="resize-vertical" class="vertical">Notice this allows only vertical resize!</textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Inspected this comment box I'm typing in; S/O uses `resize:vertical` :) It seems to be the "correct" solution if you are looking to resize vertically as much as you want!

Answer (score 1):

I'm hoping you are having the same problem that I *had*... my issue was simple: Make a fixed textarea with locked percentages inside the container (I'm new to CSS/JS/HTML, so bear with me, if I don't get the lingo correct) so that no matter the device it's displaying on, the box filling the container (the table cell) takes up the correct amount of space. Here's how I solved it:

```
<table width=100%>
    <tr class="idbbs">
        B.S.:
    </tr></br>
    <tr>
        <textarea id="bsinpt"></textarea>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Then CSS Looks like this...

```
#bsinpt
{
    color: gainsboro;
    float: none;
    background: black;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: "Helvetica", "Tahoma", "Verdana", "Arial Black", sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  min-height: 60%;
  min-width: 88%;
  max-height: 60%;
  max-width: 88%;
  resize: none;
    border-top-color: lightsteelblue;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-left-color: lightsteelblue;
    border-left-width: 1px;
    border-right-color: lightsteelblue;
    border-right-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-color: lightsteelblue;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
}
```

Sorry for the sloppy code block here, but I had to show you what's important and I don't know how to insert quoted CSS code on this website. In any case, to ensure you see what I'm talking about, the important CSS is less indented here...

What I then did (as shown here) is very specifically tweak the percentages until I found the ones that worked perfectly to fit display, no matter what device screen is used.

Granted, I think the "resize: none;" is overkill, but better safe than sorry and now the consumers will not have anyway to resize the box, nor will it matter what device they are viewing it from.

It works great.

Comment: Your HTML is formatted incorrectly. The TR needs a TD.

Answer (score 0):

```
textarea {
width: 700px;  
height: 100px;
resize: none; }
```

> assign your required width and height for the textarea and then use. 
>   **resize: none ;** css property which will disable the textarea's stretchable property.

Comment: That's the same as the main answer.