# how to limit the draggable width of a <textarea>

Tags: html, css

I have a "textarea" tag on a html modal, and it can be resized, but if I drag and resize the "textarea" it can be dragged out the range of modal.

If I can limit the draggable area of the "textarea"?

Example: [Textarea that stretches outside the range of its parent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n83Rt.png)

Comment: Please elaborate more on your question. At least show us your code and what you've tried so far. It's probably as simple as giving max. values to the textarea.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable resizable property of textarea?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235142/how-to-disable-resizable-property-of-textarea)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I prevent the textarea from stretching beyond his parent DIV element? (google-chrome issue only)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899463/how-can-i-prevent-the-textarea-from-stretching-beyond-his-parent-div-element-g)

Comment: @Goombah I don't have demo code in hand, but I added image link which is the screenshort.

Answer (score 5):

```
textarea {
   resize: none;
}
```

Hope this will help you

Besides,

```
textarea { 
resize: vertical; 
}

textarea { 
resize: horizontal; 
}
```

This codes will allow you to resize only vertically or only horizontal.

Comment: Nmm, I added an img. as you can see I want the textarea can be stretched both horizontal and vertical.

Comment: Also add max-width,max-height to restrict the dimensions, if you want user to resize

Answer (score 4):

Set max width 100% like following:

textarea { max-width:100%;}

Comment: Thanks! you are right! I also found this in the post recommend in top.