# Set max-width for textarea within fieldset

Tags: css, textarea, fieldset

I want to restrict the stretching of a textarea to 100% of the parent fieldset.

According to this question it works, when the parent is a div:
[How can I prevent the textarea from stretching beyond his parent DIV element? (google-chrome issue only)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899463/how-can-i-prevent-the-textarea-from-stretching-beyond-his-parent-div-element-g)

Now with **fieldsets** this doesn't seem to work: http://jsfiddle.net/b4oLy135/7/

HTML

```
<fieldset id="container">
    <textarea></textarea>
</fieldset>
```

CSS

```
textarea {
    max-width: 50%;
}
#container {
    max-width: 80%;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following.

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 80%;
  overflow: none;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
}

textarea {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 40%;
  max-width: calc(100% - 15px);
  height: 40%;
  max-height: calc(100% - 15px);
 }
```

```html
<fieldset id="container">
    <textarea></textarea>
</fieldset>
```

This way the `textarea` can only be resized to the width & height of its parent `fieldset`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have more then one `<input>` in your fieldset, absolute positioning does not work.

My solution was to just use a  wrapper over every `<textarea>` field, so I could use [the solution I referred to in t the question](http://How%20can%20I%20prevent%20the%20textarea%20from%20stretching%20beyond%20his%20parent%20DIV%20element?%20(google-chrome%20issue%20only)).

**Important:** <del>Does not work when using `%` on the parent.</del> There is a bug when using `%` and stretching over 200% of the parent.

Here is my current fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/d23hgb8w/3/

HTML

```
<fieldset>
    <div class="textarea__wrapper">
      <textarea></textarea>
    </div>
    
    <input>
</fieldset>
```

CSS

```
.textarea__wrapper {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 500px;
}

textarea {
  max-width: 100%;
 }
```